# What is the maximum value of (a + k b) mod M?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

where k is an integer. a, b, and M are fixed values.
Due to modulo max value is `M-1` but it may/may not be achievable, depending on the value of a and b.

if `gcd(b,M) = 1` then b is invertible modulo M. Thus `M-1` is achievable.

```
a+k.b congruent M - 1 (mod M)
```

So, if we select `k as (M - 1 - a)b' mod M`, we can get M-1. (b' is modular multiplicative inverse of b)

what happens if `gcd(b,M) != 1`?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes if you edit the question to show more of your work. Can you answer your question using brute force search for small values of $M$? Please use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hint: If $\gcd(b, M) = \color{red}1$, then $M-\color{red}1$ is the maximum acheivable value. Is there a connection here, perhaps?

Comment: @Arthur I've edited the question to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recall Bezout's identity:** If we have two integers $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $gcd(a,b) = d, d \in \mathbb{Z} \implies \exists k,s \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ak + bs = d$.

As you've correctly induced, when $gcd(b,M) = 1$, we can say that the max achievable value is $M-1$. A good way to proceed further in describing the max values is to try and leverage Bezout's identity to maybe see a connection along the lines of $gcd(b,M) = d \implies$ max value is dependent on $d$?

*Hint:* Consider $a \equiv b \pmod{M} \iff a = b + kM, \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Ok here's the justification for why it is $(M-d) + (a \mod{d})$.

Consider $a + bk \equiv c \mod{M}$. We want to try and make $c$ as large as possible. Rewrite this as $bk \equiv c-a \mod{M}$. Now consider the following:

\begin{gather*}
bk \equiv c-a \mod M \implies \exists k', bk = (c-a) + k'M \\
bk + (k')M = (c-a) 
\end{gather*}

So now denote $gcd(b,M) = d$. By Bezout's identity, we know that we can choose $k,k'$ such that the LHS above goes to $d$. Similarily we can choose them such that it goes to some multiple of $d$. So we choose it as high as possible such that (if we denote that multiple as $m$), $md < M$, which we see can just be $M-d$ (since d | M). Now notice that what we are considering is a potential candidate for $(c-a)$ so we don't want the addition of $a$ to bring $M-d + a \geq M$ for fear of the value resting down to zero. We try then to choose the multiple so that our max value lands in the range $[M-d,M)$ which we can see to be $M-d+(a \mod d)$ (since $(a \mod d) < d$.)

Comment: From what I've derived, I think the max value should be M - d + (a mod d).

Comment: Oops it seems you are right, my conclusion was hasty, Let me work that out real fast.

Comment: Yes, have changed that last statement in the second to last paragraph.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your derivation is correct =). in general, when dealing with modular arithmetic, if you haven't tried Bezout's identity, do so =).

Comment: I'm not too sure whether I've followed the correct path in deriving. Can you please show the steps?

Comment: Why don't you update your question with the steps you've taken? It'll be useful for those who come onto this problem as well.

Comment: The max value is of the form (a mod d) + n.d for some integer n. But since we want the score to be in the range [0,M), we can only choose n in the range [0, M/d). The maximum possible among these is therefore (a mod d) + (M/d -1 ).d = (M - d) + a mod d.

Comment: Ok adding my justification to =).